# How do I get docker service errors

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I did a docker swarm update to add a mount with "--mount-add". I got an error that was cut off on the terminal. While I've solved this particular issue myself, how do I continue to get error messages in the future that appear here?

Is there a way to get that error either from docker service update command (that's not cut off) or from the local logs of the manager node (if the error likely occurred on worker nodes)

Answer (score 0):

You can check docker service errors like this:

1. Use `docker service ls` to display a list of services
2. Select the ID of the desired service from the list that opens and execute `docker service logs <service_id>`